# Set weight and bias tensors of tensorflow conv2d operation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have been given a trained neural network in torch and I need to rebuild it exactly in tensorflow. I believe I have correctly defined the network's architecture in tensorflow but I am having trouble transferring the weight and bias tensors. Using a third party package, I converted all the weight and bias tensors from the torch network to numpy arrays then wrote them to disk. I can load them back into my python program but I cannot figure out a way to assign them to the corresponding layers in my tensorflow network.

For instance, I have a convolution layer defined in tensorflow as

```
kernel_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([11,11,3,64], stddev=0.1))
conv_kernel_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, kernel_1, [1,4,4,1], padding='SAME')
biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros[64])
bias_layer_1 = tf.nn_add(conv_kernel_1, biases_1)
```

According to the tensorflow documentation, the tf.nn.conv2d operation uses the shape defined in the kernel_1 variable to construct the weight tensor. However, I cannot figure out how to access that weight tensor to set it to the weight array I have loaded from file.

**Is it possible to explicitly set the weight tensor? And if so, how?**

(The same question applies to bias tensor.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have the weights and biases in a NumPy array, it should be easy to connect them into your TensorFlow network:

```
weights_1_array = ...  # ndarray of weights for layer 1
biases_1_array = ...  # ndarray of biases for layer 1

conv_kernel_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights_1_array, [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
bias_layer_1 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_kernel_1, biases_1_array)
```

Note that you must ensure that `weights_1_array` and `biases_1_array` are in the correct data format. See the documentation for [`tf.nn.conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) for an explanation of the required filter shape.

Comment: I have tried that approach and it gives me an error ValueError: Shape (64, 363) must have rank 4. My understanding is that the filter parameter defines how the weight tensor is constructed

Comment: Or do I need to reshape the loaded weight tensor? Would it preserve the values during execution?

Comment: Yes, you may need to reshape the weight tensor. The `tf.nn.conv2d()` op requires that it be 4-D, with dimensions `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`.

Comment: (If it is a 1 x 1 convolution, you might be able to do `tf.reshape(weights_1_array, [1, 1, 64, 363])`, for example.)