# VGG19 from tf.keras does not support indexing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I'm loading a standalone VGG19 in a Ubuntu virtual machine with Tensorflow1.14.0 like this :

```
VGG19 = scipy.io.loadmat(path_VGG19) #stored in my disc
VGG19_layers = VGG19['layers'][0]
```

and then I pass it to the function _conv2dWithRelu():

```
def _conv2dWithRelu(prev_layer, n_layer, layer_name,VGG19_layers):
    # get weights for this layer:
    weights = VGG19_layers[n_layer][0][0][2][0][0]
    W = tf.constant(weights)
    bias = VGG19_layers[n_layer][0][0][2][0][1]
    b = tf.constant(np.reshape(bias, (bias.size)))
    # create a conv2d layer
    conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(prev_layer, filter=W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b    
    # add a ReLU function and return
    return tf.nn.relu(conv2d)
```

however, when I want to use VGG19 from tensorflow.keras to suppress the two fully connected layers FC in order to manage the image input size, I load it  like this :

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

model = VGG19(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(1200, 1600,  
        3))) #my target input shape
VGG19_layers = model.layers
```

The problem is when I call the function _conv2dWithRelu() defined above, I'm getting the following error :

```
TypeError: 'InputLayer' object does not support indexing
```

I think that function function should be updated (re written) to use it with VGG19 from tensorflow.keras. How could I adapt it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to figure out the problem. If you show the result from `model.layers` you will see each layer is an object type

`[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f550fc09510>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550f0c8ed0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ed32fd0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f550eca3b10>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ecb5c10>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ecc3ad0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f550ecd6910>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec5d190>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec69850>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec7a6d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec7a850>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f550ec1aed0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec220d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec2cbd0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ed5b110>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f5516559210>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f5516558810>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ec54b90>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ebdbe10>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ebedf90>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f550ebfe7d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f550ec11790>]`

When you are indexing them by VGG19_layers[n_layer][0][0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bias_add)[0][0] you cant obtain it. You should replace `VGG19_layers[n_layer].weights()` for weights and `VGG19_layers[n_layer].bias()` instead.

For details, `VGG19_layers[1].weights[0]` [0] is the index for weights. You can hand on it yourself to suit your problems.
`<tf.Variable 'block1_conv1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 64) dtype=float32>`

Furthermore, the VGG19_layers[0] will be the Input layer with no weights and bias. Therefore, you should start your layers from `[1]`, not `[0]`
 `VGG19_layers[0].weights "results": []`

When I examine your code, look like you are trying to keeps the weights of the convolutional layer and pass it through relu. Then instead of slicing the weights like what you did, you should copy the whole weights to the filter at the new convolutional you created. In order to do that, I suggest you use tf2.x. When you check the value of a weights layer in tf2.x, they will give you the matrix for that filters and you can call it by

`weights = tf.constant(VGG19_layers[1].weights[0].numpy())`

according to [their requirement](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) for filters is a 4d tensor

Then you just need to pass to the convolutional

`conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filters=weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')`

```
The output is ok: `<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5, 5, 64), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-4.9203668e+00,  3.2815304e-01,  1.2678468e-01, ...,
          -1.8555930e+00,  1.6412614e-01, -7.1041006e-01],
         [-5.3053970e+00,  6.5529823e-01,  8.3891630e-01, ...,
          -3.1440034e+00,  2.6984088e+00,  1.3087101e+00],
         [-3.3932714e+00,  8.7002671e-01,  1.2363169e+00, ...,
          -2.6702189e+00,  4.4932485e+00,  2.9435217e+00],
         [-5.1859131e+00,  3.8122973e-01,  2.3676270e-01, ...,
....`
```

The same thing you will do with the [tf.nn.bias_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bias_add)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that I should replace "weights = VGG19_layers[n_layer][0][0][2][0][0]" by "weights=VGG19_layers[n_layers].weights[0][0][2][0][0]" and  "bias=VGG19_layers[n_layers].bias[0][0][2][0][1]"  by "bias=VGG19_layers[n_layers].bias[0][0][2][0][1]". When doing this, I'm getting the error "index out of range" related to bias.

Comment: When I look into the bias, its kernel is a vector 64 elements, therefore, you can only index once to access them: `VGG19_layers[1].bias`                                                   
Out: `<tf.Variable 'block1_conv1/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>`

Comment: VGG19_layers[1].bias[0]

Comment: thank you very much. I will try to update my code with your recommandation. Can I ask later if I the code still not working?

Comment: sure. No problem mate

Comment: yes. Then you should open chat. :D btw, you can select bias by VGG19_layers[1].weights[1]. So I think you don't have to copy the weight like that. Just copy the object

Comment: I'm back again, sorry I don't have a strong background in Keras or TensorFlow. Please, I didn't succeed to run the code with the modifications you recommend. Is it possible to update your answer where you redefine the function conv2dWithRelu() taking into account the novel notations you mention?

Comment: I have updated my solution for you. Sorry that I can't write the whole code for you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last question, when you say the same thing for "bias". Does it mean this : bias = tf.constant(VGG19_layers[1].weights[1].numpy()) #index on weights is 1 not 0  ?
I understanded how you get the weights. But how can I get the bias?

Comment: yes. but, be sure that your convolution has bias. You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223157/set-weight-and-bias-tensors-of-tensorflow-conv2d-operation for how to add that bias to the layer in tensorflow :D if you dont get my point :))

Comment: I updated my code according to your recommandations. However I was faced an issue which got me crazy. I opened a new issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207935/numpy-unavailable-even-if-eager-execution-is-enabled 
It would be so helpful if you can see it. thank you